# How to automatically delete documents when boolean is false and time is up in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

so I have this schema:

```
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
    },
    username: { type: String },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    points: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    location: {
      type: String,
    },
    validation: {
      type: String,
    },
    isValidated: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    roles: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Role",
      },
    ],
    password: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  { collection: "users" }
)
```

Now that I'm trying to id is to delete this document automatically after 2 minutes if this parameter `isValidated` is set to false. I know if I set expire_at it will delete document, but don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would just set expire_at to 2 minutes in the future in the same place you set isValidated to false.

```
 //Pseudocode because I'm not sure the exact syntax for this
 let invalidate = (document) => {
     document.isValidated = false
     date = new Date()
     date += 2 minutes
     document.expire_at = date
     document.save()
 }
```